# How to tell Firefox where to find my plugin?

Tags: firefox, plugins, embed

I have a webpage that uses a custom plugin, like this:

```
<embed height="0" width="0" type="application/mozilla-plugin-myplugin" id="myplugin">
```

Now, whenever someone visits this page without the plugin installed, Firefox popups a yellow bar telling the user that not all plugins are installed. So far so good.

But, when the user presses the button in the yellow bar to get help installing the plugin, Firefox of course can't find it.

So, the question is: How do I tell Firefox the url where my plugin can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the pluginspage attribute to tell the browser where to find the plugin. [This](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED.html) article will help.